# x:bind UI not update when PropertyChanged in UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I'm using `x:Bind` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update UI in UWP application. But it behaves like `OneTime` binding even though I set it to `OneWay`.

`Bindings.Update()` works, but I want to know why `INotifyPropertyChanged` fails.

XAML

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind staffVM.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
private StaffViewModel staffVM;
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // I want to change staffVM according to ListView's selection.
    staffVM = staffListView.SelectedItem as StaffViewModel;
    staffVM.Update(); // If change this to Bindings.Update(), It works.
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class StaffViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Character character;
    public string Name => character.name == string.Empty ? null : character.name;
    public void Update()
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need to specify the name of the variable that you want to update:

```
public void Update()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
}
```

Documentation and sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged

Secondly, by default x:Bind is OneTime
To fix it, add `Mode="OneWay"`

> Mode  Specifies the binding mode, as one of these strings: "OneTime", "OneWay", or "TwoWay". The default is "OneTime". Note that this differs from the default for {Binding}, which is "OneWay" in most cases.

Please read documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension

Comment: 1. `The PropertyChanged event can indicate that all properties on the object have changed by using String.Empty for the PropertyName property of the PropertyChangedEventArgs.` according to your documentation in first part.  
2. I've already set `Mode="OneWay"`

Comment: Ok, next question is what are you expect? I cannot see in your code any changes that affect UI. Just Update method where you do nothing just invoke Property changed. But none of the properties changed. You need to change property and only after that invoke property changed event

Comment: Lol thanks for the reminder of using `OneWay`, been puzzling for the last 2 hours why a certain progress bar wouldn't update

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not on the level of the `StaffViewModel` class, but on the level of the page. When you do:

```
staffVM = staffListView.SelectedItem as StaffViewModel;
```

The UI has no notification about the fact that the `staffVM` field has changed. So the binding is still pointing to the old instance of `StaffViewModel`. Hence when you do `staffVM.Update()`, it does notify about changes, but the UI is not listening to that instance - it is still listening to notifications on the first selected item. `Bindings.Update()` fixes this because it completely re-evaluates all bindings so it will "get" the new value of `staffVM` field.

Solution would be to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `Page` and encapsulate the `staffVM` in a property which raises `PropertyChanged` event.

Ideally I would however suggest creating a "root" view model, which you will set only once and will not change and which will contain the selected item as its property. This way you don't have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `Page` and its code-behind will be simpler. As a result you will have something like the following in the code-behind:

```
public RootViewModel VM {get;} = new RootViewModel();
```

And in XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind VM.SelectedStaff.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```